Pandas get Min & max of varying range
I have following table in as df.
Price   Stop    Max Min
15       15     
5           
35          
85          
67       67     
75          
54          
17          
75       75     
52          
75          
75       75     
53          
15       15     
58          
71          
95          
45          
77       77     
65          
25          
48          
15       15     
45          

in the max column against the value of Stop i want to have max value of Price for a range till next stop figure & same for min value in Min Col.
E.g. against 15 I would need Max & Min from 15 to 67 range. i.e. 85 as max & 5 as min value in respective col.
I can get Min & Max for entire col but not for continuous changing ranges.
Example I am Using on following dataset.
Price           Stop      Max   Min
48,838.65           
48,838.65           
48,820.00           
48,842.15   -48,842.15      
48,892.95           
48,910.85           
48,928.50           
48,925.00           
48,971.05           
48,985.00           
48,960.00   48,960.00       
48,959.00           


IIUC, compute a mask with notna, then perform a groupby.agg (using cumsum to form the groups) and assign the Max/Min:
m = df['Stop'].notna()

df.loc[m, ['Max', 'Min']] = (df.groupby(m.cumsum())['Price']
                               .agg(['max', 'min']).values
                            )

Output:
    Price  Stop   Max   Min
0      15  15.0  85.0   5.0
1       5   NaN   NaN   NaN
2      35   NaN   NaN   NaN
3      85   NaN   NaN   NaN
4      67  67.0  75.0  17.0
5      75   NaN   NaN   NaN
6      54   NaN   NaN   NaN
7      17   NaN   NaN   NaN
8      75  75.0  75.0  52.0
9      52   NaN   NaN   NaN
10     75   NaN   NaN   NaN
11     75  75.0  75.0  53.0
12     53   NaN   NaN   NaN
13     15  15.0  95.0  15.0
14     58   NaN   NaN   NaN
15     71   NaN   NaN   NaN
16     95   NaN   NaN   NaN
17     45   NaN   NaN   NaN
18     77  77.0  77.0  25.0
19     65   NaN   NaN   NaN
20     25   NaN   NaN   NaN
21     48   NaN   NaN   NaN
22     15  15.0  45.0  15.0
23     45   NaN   NaN   NaN

If you want to consider both the non-NA rows before and after, you can use:
m = df['Stop'].notna()
g = df.groupby(m.cumsum())['Price']

df['Max'] = np.maximum(df.loc[m, 'Price'].shift(-1).ffill(), g.max().to_numpy())
df['Min'] = np.minimum(df.loc[m, 'Price'].shift(-1).ffill(), g.min().to_numpy())

Output:
    Price  Stop   Max   Min
0      15  15.0  85.0   5.0
1       5   NaN   NaN   NaN
2      35   NaN   NaN   NaN
3      85   NaN   NaN   NaN
4      67  67.0  75.0  17.0
5      75   NaN   NaN   NaN
6      54   NaN   NaN   NaN
7      17   NaN   NaN   NaN
8      75  75.0  75.0  52.0
9      52   NaN   NaN   NaN
10     75   NaN   NaN   NaN
11     75  75.0  75.0  15.0
12     53   NaN   NaN   NaN
13     15  15.0  95.0  15.0
14     58   NaN   NaN   NaN
15     71   NaN   NaN   NaN
16     95   NaN   NaN   NaN
17     45   NaN   NaN   NaN
18     77  77.0  77.0  15.0
19     65   NaN   NaN   NaN
20     25   NaN   NaN   NaN
21     48   NaN   NaN   NaN
22     15  15.0  45.0  15.0
23     45   NaN   NaN   NaN


I Used in different dataset & Received this error. ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (25,) (26,)

Can you provide an example @rakesh?

Edited in Question. The data has 375 rows hence cant attach here

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Sample DataFrame
data = {
    'Price': [15, 5, 35, 85, 67, 75, 54, 17, 75, 52, 75, 75, 53, 15, 58, 71, 95, 45, 77, 65, 25, 48, 15, 45],
    'Stop': [15, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 67, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 75, np.nan, np.nan, 75, np.nan, 15, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 77, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 15, np.nan],
}


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
'''
pydev debugger: starting (pid: 12016)
    Price  Stop
0      15  15.0
1       5   NaN
2      35   NaN
3      85   NaN
4      67  67.0
5      75   NaN
6      54   NaN
7      17   NaN
8      75  75.0
9      52   NaN
10     75   NaN
11     75  75.0
12     53   NaN
13     15  15.0
14     58   NaN
15     71   NaN
16     95   NaN
17     45   NaN
18     77  77.0
19     65   NaN
20     25   NaN
21     48   NaN
22     15  15.0
23     45   NaN
'''

df['Stop'] = df['Stop'].ffill()
df['group'] = (df['Stop'] != df['Stop'].shift()).cumsum()
df = df.merge(df.groupby('group')['Price'].agg(['max', 'min']).reset_index(),
               on='group', how='left')

print(df)
'''
  Price  Stop  group  max  min
0      15  15.0      1   85    5
1       5  15.0      1   85    5
2      35  15.0      1   85    5
3      85  15.0      1   85    5
4      67  67.0      2   75   17
5      75  67.0      2   75   17
6      54  67.0      2   75   17
7      17  67.0      2   75   17
8      75  75.0      3   75   52
9      52  75.0      3   75   52
10     75  75.0      3   75   52
11     75  75.0      3   75   52
12     53  75.0      3   75   52
13     15  15.0      4   95   15
14     58  15.0      4   95   15
15     71  15.0      4   95   15
16     95  15.0      4   95   15
17     45  15.0      4   95   15
18     77  77.0      5   77   25
19     65  77.0      5   77   25
20     25  77.0      5   77   25
21     48  77.0      5   77   25
22     15  15.0      6   45   15
23     45  15.0      6   45   15

'''

